# DataObject is being sorted alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting, object

I have a dataobject which I want to use in my presentation layer, bind it to a grid etc.

For some reasons the object gets sorted alphabetically

Example:

```
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE- I missed out the most important part which is - this is a WCF dataobject

When I load the data and try to consume it, it is sorted alphabetically by:

EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, Username

I would like to display it using this sorting:

Username, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress

Data from database - username,firstname,lastname,emailaddress 
Data from the service - emailaddress,firstname,lastname,username

DataObject is designed as shown above

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you show us the code for how you're grid is set-up? Is it a asp.net grid or a windows forms grid?

Comment: Also, got to show how you are reading the data from the data source. If you use SQL Select, the data will be returned in the order of columns presented in the select or if you use SELECT *, the order will be determined by the order of columns in the schema.

Comment: Its a radgrid but the data gets sorted even before it gets to the grid

Comment: I have my database table column structure in the same order as my object and that is not in the alphabetical order

Comment: The real issue isn't with your `User` class. It has to deal with how you are displaying it. That's why @JordanW asked to see how you are displaying the information.

Comment: List<User> users = new List<User>();
users = GetAllUsers();
RadGrid1.DataSource = users
RadGrid1.DataBind();

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".